# How do i validate user input in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, validation, kohana-3, xss

I'm looking for a PHP class that will help me validate my user input from a form. For example, making sure the user has entered the mandatory fields, that the fields did not exceed their maximum length, that the user has entered a number in the "age" field and so on... If not i want to display the user an error and log that error to a database. also, if possible with the same class to prevent sql injection & xss from user inputs.
Is there a PHP 5 class that will help me do all of these tasks? (Or multiple classes?)

Comment: Since you have tagged this `kohana`, have you looked into it? http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/security/validation

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say something like you want to check if the user has entered all the fields correctly on the server side using PHP? If yes, then your method is quite inefficient as it will increase the traffic and load on the server for wrong submissions. So what generally is done is a Javascript client side script is used to validate the forms before submission. This link can help you to implement a simple client side validation in Javascript. http://www.elated.com/articles/form-validation-with-javascript/

As deceze pointed out, if you need server side validation using PHP, then this link has a simple example on how to do it using some built in functions. http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/php-form-validation/

Comment: He still needs server-side validation regardless.

Comment: He needs server-side validation for the second time after data is validated on the client side itself? Can you please explain why? I dont know. That's why I am asking.

Comment: Really? What if the client doesn't have Javascript? Or deliberately turns it off? Or doesn't even use a browser to (maliciously) POST data to the server? Do you just want to let unvalidated data through?

Comment: Good point. Didn't think of it that way. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: First lesson about web applications: Always always distrust the client and any code running on it. Your server is the big black box that decides over everything and treats every input as hostile until quarantined. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$post = Validate::factory($_POST)

->filter(TRUE, 'trim')
->rule('name','not_empty')
->rule('age','not_empty')
```

Above code represents how to use it. For more reference, please visit the following link

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/security/validation

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you can use both javascript frameworks(ie. jquery) and php at the same time.

your html form posts an ajax data to server. your server returns various error or success codes. then you can manipulate your html using jquery.
here is a sample on client side usinf jquery;

```
    $( "a#logSubmit").click(function(){
    $.post("/control.php?process=login", {username: $('input#logName').val(), password: $('input#logPass').val()},
   function(data) {
     if(data == "ok"){
     //success
     $( "#dialog-login" ).dialog("close");
     }
     else{
         $("label#input").html("your input is not valid");
         }
   });
});
```

and your php side should be similar like this

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['nik']) or !isset($_POST['pass']))
{
    die("not ok");
}
if($_POST['nik']=="" or $_POST['pass'] =="")
{

    die("not ok");
}

//here you can`enter code here` validate your data and issue a custom error or success response.

//success!
die('ok');
?>
```